# Qmake build and gcc includes

Tags: qt, qmake, qt4.7

I am working with Qt and kinda new to it. I want to build a Qt application and created devprog.pro file. However, after executing *qmake* and *make*  I get the error

> c:\qt473\include\qtcore../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h(45)
>   : fatal error C10 83: Cannot open
>   include file: 'stddef.h': No such file
>   or directory

So I specified the gcc 4.4.1 include location and the error messages (amongst others) I get is:

> c:\codeblocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\stddef.h(211)
>   : error C2371: ' size_t' :
>   redefinition; different basic types
>           predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(19) : see declaration of
>   'size_ t'
>   C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\string.h(126)
>   : error C2143: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before '*'
>   C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\string.h(126)
>   : error C4430: missing type specifier
>   - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

My question is: 
1. How can resolve such error problems as I've scratched my hair off trying to solve this.
2. Is there a way to make automatically let qmake detect your main gcc mingw location without having to set it for each project during qmake execution?

Comment: Hi, managed to solve the above issue. It may help another "novice". I tried to check the default _italic_ QMAKESPEC config and realized it was set (at installation of QT4.7.3) to win32-msvc2008 and changed it to win32-g++ . But now I have another error **_italic_ o:/mfitDEV/debug/moc_RenderThread.cpp:69: undefined reference to `QThread::qt_me
tacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)'
./debug\moc_RenderThread.o(.text+0x251): In function `ZN12RenderThread17setProgr
essThreadEi':
o:/mfitDEV/debug/moc_RenderThread.cpp:87: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11QMe
taObject8activateEP7QObjectPKS_iPPv'**

Comment: Have you tried forcing qmake to re-run and/or deleting all of the generated ui_*, moc_*, Makefiles, and object files?  Most of the time I see "weird" error messages it's because the generated files got out of sync and need to be rebuilt.  [BTW, `make distclean` will do the cleanup for you.]